# load partial view by using jquery

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I want to display a partial view into a div. I have tried many methods but not get the result.

please provide me a proper solution I'm new at mvc

this is main ****index page****

```
@model TelerikAdmin.Models.ViewModel.UserViewModel

        @{
            ViewBag.Title = "Index";
           // Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutPage1.cshtml";
        }
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            .k-ff input.k-textbox {
                height: 2.17em;
                width:350px;

            }
            .content-wrapper {
                margin:5% auto auto 25%;
                border:1px solid yellow;
                width:550px;
            }
            #container tr td{
                padding:10px;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            $(function () {
                $('#loadFromMainFrame').click(function (e) {
                    e.preventdefault();
                    var url = $(this).data(url);
                    $('#mainframeContens').load(url);
                });
            });
        </script>
        <input id="loadFromMainFrame" type="button" data-url="@Url.Action("GetView","Privilege")" value="Click" />
        <div id="mainframeContens">
        </div>
```

this is my partial view(patial.cshtml)
         where i place the partial view in shared folder or any other place

## This is partial view

and this my controller action

```
using Kendo.Mvc.UI;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Kendo.Mvc.Extensions;
using TelerikMvcApp5.Models.Context;
using TelerikAdmin.Models.ViewModel;

namespace TelerikAdmin.Controllers
{
    public class PrivilegeController : Controller
    {
        ShoppingContext db = new ShoppingContext();
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
         return View();
        }

        public ActionResult GetView()
        {
            return PartialView("partial");
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Use like below.

**Change Your JS like below.**

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#loadFromMainFrame').click(function (e) {
            e.preventdefault();

            var url = $(this).data(url);

            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'GET',
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#mainframeContens').html(result);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Note: **Your Partial View load Div Should be like below.**

```
<div id="mainframeContens">
    @Html.Partial("partial")
</div>
```

Mention the HTTPGET like below in your Action method

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetView()
{
    return PartialView("partial");
}
```